# Method to automate simulation runs

Tags: python, json, simulation, configuration-files, ini

I have created a discrete event simulation in Python that takes a set number of inputs, currently held in a database table, and produces output which is also stored in the database (SQLite). I have implemented the ability to run multiple replications (as there is some randomness in the simulation) with a given set of inputs. I now wish to be able to run the simulation with multiple sets of inputs without having to manually change the inputs after each run. However I am not sure as to the best way to achieve this.

My current thinking is to have a script that can create a JSON file that contains the inputs for each run. For example:

Input data table (extremely simplified for explanation):

```
id name     input 1 input 2
1  Entity 1   67      red
2  Entity 2   54      blue
```

JSON example (again simplified to match above input):

```
{"simulation inputs":[      
    {"run 1":
        "replications": 100,
        "entity 1": "name of entity"
             {
              "input 1": 67,
              "input 2": "red"   
              }
        "entity 2": "a different entity of same class with different values"
             {
              "input 1": 54,
              "input 2": "blue"   
              }

    },
    {"run 2":
        "replications": 100,
        "entity 1": "name of entity"
             {
              "input 1": 69,
              "input 2": "red"   
              }
        "entity 2": "a different entity of same class with different values"
             {
              "input 1": 54,
              "input 2": "blue"   
              }
    },
    {"run 3":
        "replications": 100,
        "entity 1": "name of entity"
             {
              "input 1": 71,
              "input 2": "red"   
              }
        "entity 2": "a different entity of same class with different values"
             {
              "input 1": 54,
              "input 2": "blue"   
              }
    },
]}
```

As per the above example which contains the information for three runs where one input is adjusted for each run -  input 1 for entity 1. In a real situation there could be a large number of variations in the inputs for which there would be 1 run entry in the config file for each.  The Python program would run through the list in the JSON file using the defined values as the inputs for that particular run. The outputs being stored in the database. Each of the entities is an instance of the same class with different values for the inputs.

Is the above a sensible approach? If no what other approaches could there be? If yes is there an implementation of such functionality,or similar, anywhere already I could use as a starting point?

I have had a good search but, perhaps as I am not familiar with configuration file terminology, have not been able to find a suitable answer.

note: edited to better represent the type of input data that will be used.

Many thanks.

Comment: Which DB do you use to store your inputs? You could gets all rows from your table as simple dictionary and iterate over it to run all the simulations.

Comment: I'm using SQLite. The example I gave was quite simple. I've edited it to better reflect the input data that will be varied as well as included an example of some of the input data.

Comment: There's no generic solution for this, writing custom scripts to revise the input sets and collate the output is a platform- and model-specific task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the JSON file technique and it works very well so I thought I would share the answer.

A JSON file is created. In may case the top level is a key that identifies a "run" - essentially a unique combination of inputs. The value is another dictionary that contains all the values used to setup the simulation, such as the number of replications -  as a DES needs multiple reps. It is simply loaded using the in built JSON functionality in Python.

```
with open(file_name) as data_file:
input_data = json.load(data_file)  # dict of the whole file
```

So at this stage we have input_data which is simply a dictionary of the whole file. By extracting the top level key and looping through each you are able to sequentially pass each runs inputs into the simulation. For each run you are only passing the set of inputs you need to pass, not the whole dictionary.

```
list_of_runs = sorted(list(input_data.keys()), key=int) 
for run in list_of_runs:

replications = input_data[run]['replications']

reps = 0
```

The next loop runs the simulation the defined number of times using the same set of inputs each time.

```
for reps in range(replications):

    current_run = initialize.Run(input_data[run])
    '''some other code here'''

    env.run(until=end)

    reps += 1
```

In my actual code "Run" is a class and within that class other classes are defined each being passed the portion of the original JSON file they need. This means when a class needs to access a value if only needs look within the dictionary that is has been passed and all of these dictionaries are updated automatically as the code runs through each of the runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input table in which each row refers to a set of inputs for a single run, you could do something like the following.

```
import sqlite3

db_path = "C:/.../mydatabase.db"
connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
cursor = connection.cursor()

#get parameters from table
for row in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM input_table'):
    param1 = row[0]
    param2 = row[1]
    ...
    go_for_simulation(param1, param2,...)
```

Each `row` variable in the loop is a tuple that contains all your parameters. 
I hope this approach could help you.